# Grep Regex Exclusion Special Character

Tags: regex, grep

I am having a difficult time trying to search for a phrase but exclude the phrase if it is directly followed by a colon-space.

I am looking for Delet! (i.e. "Delet.*" in regex syntax) but I do not want anything returned that is "Deleted: " (includes a space after the colon). However, I would like anything returned that is "Deleted" followed by anything other than a colon-space.

I have tried the following expressions

```
grep -ri 'delet.*[^:]'

grep -ri 'delet[a-zA-Z0-9\;\".....]{0,10}'
```

(including all special characters in the range preceded by escapes)

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I did not even realize I used one of those phrases. Will not use it in the future.

Comment: Post some sample input and expected output as it's not clear exactly what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

If I got you correctly you want anything starting with `delet`, and not starting with `deleted:`:

```
grep -Ei '^delet((([^e]|e$)|e([^d]|d$)|ed([^:]|:$)|ed:[^ ]).*)?$'
```

This basically says:

- Match `[start]deletX[anything][end]` or `[start]delete[end]` where `X` is not `e`
- Match `[start]deleteX[anything][end]` or `[start]deleted[end]` where `X` is not `d`
- Match `[start]deletedX[anything][end]` or `[start]deleted:[end]` where `X` is not `:`
- Match `[start]deleted:X[anything][end]` where `X` is not space.

It would have been far easier to use pipe and second negative grep if that is applicable:

```
grep -i ^delet | grep -vi '^deleted: '
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a lookahead expression:

```
grep -Pi 'Delet(?!ed: )'
```

Note the modification of the parameters of `grep`: `-P` enables the use of lookahead expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. The `?` after the `*` instructs it to select as few non-space characters as possible, followed by any one character that is not a colon, followed by a space.

```
grep -ri 'delet[^ ]*?[^:] '
```

Comment: This wont match things like `delet`, `delete`, `deleted`, `delete:`, `delete :` etc.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like all you need is:

```
awk -v IGNORECASE=1 '/delet/ && !/deleted: /' file
```

The above uses GNU awk for IGNORECASE, other awks would use tolower().

The benefit of awk over grep is that awk tests for conditions, not just regexps, so you can create compound conditions using `&&` and `||` out of tests for regexps which makes it MUCH simpler and clearer to just code the condition you want to test - that the line contains `delet` and (`&&`) not (`!`) `deleted:`.